# How to get the relations between the tables while importing the sql server database in VBA(ms access)form application?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access, database-migration

I am importing all the sql server tables into VBA form application using "ExternalData" linq datasource option .Then able to access the tables,but not getting any relationships between the tables.Please tell me how to get the table relationships while importing the tables into VBA form.?

any possible solution give me ,

Comment: Are you linking to the tables on SQL server? If yes, then all you need is for each form and the correspond sub form is to set the link master/child settings. The relationships will thus be handled by the server, and Access will correctly maintain the link master/child relations for you. It not clear if you just linking to SQL server, or importing data to local tables. Is the data you are editing on SQL server or local?

Comment: already in sql server having links.by using "ExternalData" link option importing all tables into VBA then while seeing the relationship in VBA form application not applyed any relations between tables.how to get that relations while importing the tables from sql server to VBA form application.

Comment: I want to import data that's stored in a SQL Server into Access, Is
there a way to pull in the relationships as well? I know when you do linked
tables you can see the relationships but when I import the data I don't see
the relationships.